# Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. Parameter name: index

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have the following code inside my view inside an asp.net mvc-4 web application:-

```
@model IList<TS.ViewModels.ACCOUNTLIST>

@for(int i2 = 0; i2 < (Model.Count() <= 0 ? 5 : Model.Count()); i2++) { 

    <div>

        <span >@Html.DisplayFor(m => m[i2].ACCOUNTNAME) </span>@Html.EditorFor(m => m[i2].ACCOUNTNAME) </div>
          <div>

        <span >@Html.DisplayFor(m => m[i2].PASSWORD) </span>@Html.EditorFor(m => m[i2].PASSWORD) </div>
          <div>

        <span >@Html.DisplayFor(m => m[i2].NOTES) </span>@Html.EditorFor(m => m[i2].NOTES) </div>

}
```

now what i am trying to accomplish is to display a five empty set of fields if the Model is empty. and in-case the Model contain data to display the related date.. but currently when i render the view and the passed model is empty i will get the following exception :-

```
Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. Parameter name: index
```

but if i use `Html.Display` and `Html.Editor` as follow , my view will work well:-

```
@for(int i2 = 0; i2 < (Model.Count() <= 0 ? 5 : Model.Count()); i2++) { 

    <div>

        <span class="f">@Html.Display("["+i2.ToString()+"].ACCOUNTNAME") </span>@Html.Editor("["+i2.ToString()+"].ACCOUNTNAME") 


        <span class="f">@Html.Display("["+i2.ToString()+"].PASSWORD") </span>@Html.Editor("["+i2.ToString()+"].PASSWORD") </div>




}
```

So can anyone adivce on this please? why i can not use the `Html.DisplayFor` & `Html.EditorFor` in my case?

Comment: When your model is empty, and so its `Count` is `0`, what do you expect to happen when you ask for `m[0]` ?

Comment: Your `for` is strange - are you sure you've got the correct true and false part of the tenary?

Comment: @AakashM to render an empty input and label.. now if i replace Html.Displayfor and Html.Editorfor with Html.Display & Html.Editor it will work fine ...

Comment: @AllanS.Hansen why it is strange ?... i want to show 5 empty sets of the divs if the model is empty... now if i replace Html.Displayfor and Html.Editorfor with Html.Display & Html.Editor it will work fine ..so there is not any thing strange.. but i want to  use the strongly typed html helpers..

Comment: @johnG Because you iterate over model and bind from model when model is 0. Hence it looked like a flipped logic. And likely why you get index exceptions

Comment: @AllanS.Hansen i did not get your point ,, i am not doing anything unusual ... as i know if the model does not have the related values then the DisplayFor and EditorFor will render empty name and input fields ,, so there is nothing exceptional here. for example when you render a Create view the model will be empty but the Displayfor and Editorfor will show empty create view !!.. second point why if i use Html.Display & Html.Editor my intended logic will work fine

Comment: @johnG `m[i2]` - what does that return when i2 is - say 4 and your model is 0?

Comment: @johnG It's not DisplayFor that's the problem, it's your index out of bound. The reason Display "works" but not DisplayFor is that you're not accessing through an index. Display and DisplayFor isn't doing the same. `m[i2]` is most likely your culprit and should be easily detectable via debugging. (regardless of numbers of exclamation marks).

Comment: @AllanS.Hansen ok i got your point .. so now i want my vew to be general and will be rendered as partial for multiple main views.. so i still want to handle the whole logix inside the view, by checking if the model is empty and render 5 sets of input fields. so in my case what will be the problems if i use Editor & Display as shown in my question ? or is there a way to implement this using EditorFor & DisplayFor??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you're trying to retrieve an item from the collection which doesn't exist. e.g trying to access object 4 out of a collection of 3.

To solve the problem you're having I'd remove the condition from the view and instead put it in the controller so if you wish to show more empty entries in the future you wouldn't need to modify the view at all.

Replace the view for statement with the following:

```
@for (var i2 = 0; i2 < Model.Count; i2++)
{
    <div>
        <span>@Html.DisplayFor(m => m[i2].ACCOUNTNAME)</span>@Html.EditorFor(m => m[i2].ACCOUNTNAME)
    </div>
    <div>
        <span>@Html.DisplayFor(m => m[i2].PASSWORD) </span>@Html.EditorFor(m => m[i2].PASSWORD)
    </div>
    <div>
        <span>@Html.DisplayFor(m => m[i2].NOTES) </span>@Html.EditorFor(m => m[i2].NOTES)
    </div>
}
```

Then inside your controller have something along the lines of

```
// Replace this with your method of retrieving the accounts list
var accounts = new List<ACCOUNTLIST>();

const int maxEntries = 5;

while (accounts.Count < maxEntries)
{
    accounts.Add(new ACCOUNTLIST());
}

return View(accounts);
```

Comment: accessing non-exsiting data using DisplayFor and EditorFor is not the problem !!! the evidence  is that if i use Html.Display & Html.Editor , instead of displayfor and editorfor my intended logic will work fine

Comment: That is because Display and Editor are not strongly typed to the Model. Therefore it doesn't attempt to retrieve the item from the collection. It also will not bind any values from the model which then means it will only ever show blank input fields.

Comment: The binding on the submit will work as the expression you pass into the Display is the correct one. But if have say a collection of 3 accounts with data in the UI will not bind the values as seen here: [Screenshot of UI](http://i.imgur.com/POyUwDN.png)

Comment: ok you might be correct... but why Display and Editor  will work well ???? what is the reason that Display and Editor  will work while DisplayFor and EditorFor will not work ?

Comment: @johnG The reason is because the Display and Editor helpers are not strongly typed to the model, Just like David said.
Consider the term here, "for". What is it for if the collection doesn't exist?

Comment: @johnG Display and Editor aren't linked to the model you are passing in so the exception of index out of range will never occur as it's not display properties based on the values in the model. When you use those helpers you are almost just telling razor to output a label or textbox with the following name and to ignore the model.

Comment: @DavidFord ok i got your point.. so now i want my vew to be general and will be called for multiple views.. so i still want to handle the whole logix inside the view.. so in my case what will be the problems if i use Editor & Display as shown in my question ?

Comment: @johnG The main implication of using Display and Editor is that the view will not have the model's values binded to it. So there is no point in providing a model to the view at all and a simple for loop with a max entries integer is all you need. I'd put the view code I posted above into a partial view which can be reused in other parts of the web application and keep the code where it adds empty entries in the controller. It's best to do that because lets say one page only wants to render 5 entries but another wants to render 10, having it in the controllers means you get this customization.

Answer (score 1):

This condition is a little strange:

```
i2 < (Model.Count() <= 0 ? 5 : Model.Count());
```

What it states is that if the model count is less than or equal to zero then loop 5 times, else loop "model count" times.

So when the model is empty it will try to access the first 5 elements of `Model` which don't exist - hence the error.

You need to decide what you want to happen when the count is zero and code for that explicitly:

```
if (Model.Count() > 0)
{
    @for(int i2 = 0; i2 < Model.Count(); i2++)
    {
    }
}
else
{
    Do something else
}
```

Comment: so how i can specify if the model is empty to render 5 empty set of my Display-for and EditorFor.. as i know if the model does not have the related values then the DisplayFor and EditorFor will render empty name and input fields ,, so there is nothing exceptional here. for example when you render a Create view the model will be empty but the Displayfor and Editorfor will show empty create view !!.. second point why if i use Html.Display & Html.Editor my intended logic will work fine

Comment: @johnG I don't know enough about asp.net to answer that I'm afraid.

Comment: ok that's fine ,, but the way EditorFor and DisplayFor work is that they will try to find the related values if not then they will render empty names and input fields.. at the end using Html.Display & Html.Editor  in my case will work fine,, so my logic is correct ,, but seems there is a limitation when using the Html.Displayfor and Html,EditorFor

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are binding empty model data collection. I guess it would be better if you set some default values for your model collection in your Action result and render it, instead of sending an empty List. And, instead of checking if your Model is null, you just check for default values and create the fields accordingly..